# Storing XML in Active Directory

Tags: xml, active-directory

Is it wise to store XML in Active Directory?

In my project an ECM is performing a night-job and is iterating through AD and is reading XML data from each AD group....

Answer (score 1):

For small amounts of XML data Active Directory (or any other LDAP) should be fine.  I just wouldn't use it has my central database repository.  You could extend the schema of the directory object your want fields on.  But *sometimes* it's better to store blobs of data in an unused field.